# Adding custom email while creating user from social_auth(facebook, instagram)

Tags: django, facebook-authentication, django-users, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

My custom `_create_user` UserManager for creating users in my django app reads something like this.

```
def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
                raise ValueError('The email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, is_staff=is_staff, is_superuser=is_superuser, date_joined=django.utils.timezone.now(), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

When I want to create or retrieve a user from the backend, I do a call like `user = backend.do_auth(access_token, user=authed_user)`, where `backend` is either Facebook or Instagram, `authed_user` is the currently signed in user or `None`. 
Sometimes, there are no emails associated with Facebook and Instagram does not return any emails at all. In that case, I am taking a separate input for email in my front end. How do I pass it as a parameter and what sort of changes do I need to make such that, if I call `user = backend.do_auth(access_token, user=authed_user, email = 'abc@xyz.com)`, it will create a new user from the `access_token` but the email will be changed to `abc@xyz.com`. Please note that email may also be `None` in which case I would like to use the email obtained from the `access_token`, if any.